# how i will get the data by months if this row existed in previous months count 1

Tags: php, mysql

my table is

```
   Month   |   Company     |
    Jan    |   Inzpect     |
    May    |   Ginebra     |
    May    |   Inzpect     |
    Jun    |   Inzpect     |
```

My sql

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT company) as 
exist_customer FROM mirdc_jo_form 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT('2017-06-01', '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') 
AND company IN (SELECT company FROM mirdc_jo_form 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB('2017-06-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m'))
```

And i get the wrong data because this is what i get when i loop it per month in php is this

```
   Month   |   existing_company  |  
    Jan    |          0          |    
    May    |          0          |     
    Jun    |          1          |
```

My sql statement only counts 1 month before . i having a hard time that it will cover the whole rows.

my expected result is my sql  statement will count the data from this current date to the previous months if this new data was already inputted it will count as 1 because its existed in the previous months and if this data was new and there is no exact data in the previous months i will do nothing.

my expected result is

```
   Month   |   existing_company  |    new_company
    Jan    |          0          |       1
    May    |          1          |       1
    Jun    |          1          |       0
```

jan = the existing customer is 0 because Inzpect company was not register in the previous months or there is no Inzpect in the database and count it as 1 because it was a new customer

May = the existing customer is 1 because in the month of may there is 2 entry data it was inzpect and ginebra and inzpect was already inputed in jan so it will count to existing_comapny column (all data that already register in previous months will count so if there is 2 register data in the previous month that register to this month it will count as existing_company = 2, all register data that was exact the same from the previous will count)

Comment: Question not clear. In output, why jun should be 1 ? Also why only inzpect, why not Ginebra ? Are you passing them as parameter ?

Comment: my expected result is

   Month   |   existing_company  |
    Jan    |          0          |
    May    |          1          |
    Jun    |          1          |


Jan = 1 because inzpect company was new to the database
May = 1 becuase Inzpect was already register in the previous months
Jun = 1 becuase Inzpect was already register in the previous months

Please explain your question clear, There is something missing on your question.

Comment: ops sory if there is new data that will exact company from the previous months it will count as existing sory for my bad english..
example in january inzpect and ginebra was register and the another month february inzpect and ginebra was register again.. now they will count as existing.. 
in existing column it will count 2 because inzpect and ginebra was already register in the previous months

Comment: You're  acceptance rate is a bit disappointing. Just sayin'. Oh, and in case it wasn't mentioned before (or even if it was), see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: sory sr for disappointing you hayzz